# Updating Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

Why when I'm updating my Django to 3.0.5 my old Django version that I use has been removed.
All codes are not working.
What should I do if want to update my Django to latest version.
And Keep my old version.

Answer (score 0):

In Django it is advisable to use a virutal environment . It helps to keep the dependencies of projects separate and you can also have separate versions of any package according to your project requirements in different virtual environments.
In order to create a virtual environment

**For windows:**
 - Install dependencies

```
pip install virtualenv
```

- Go to your project directory
- Now in which ever directory you are, this line below will create a
  virtualenv there

  `virtualenv myenv`
- In the same directory type the folllowing to activate the virtual
  environment:

  `myenv\Scripts\activate`

Now you can install any django version . That version will be installed in this virtual environment only

- To exit from the virtual environment run :

`deactivate`

**Note: Whenever you are running any packages make sure the venv is active**

Hope it helps!